# If p is true, but q is not true, then r must be true.

Tags: proof-explanation, alternative-proof

Prove: if $x^2$+x-6 $\ge$ 0, then $x$ $\le$ -3 or $x$ $\ge$ 2.

Typically, I'd just use the factorization method to find that the roots are in fact 2 and 3. But I'm trying to find a proof that satisfies the tautology [$p$ $\Rightarrow$ ($q$ $\lor$ $r$)] $\iff$ [($p$ $\land$ $\sim$$q$) $\Rightarrow$ $r$].

I understand that the antecedent, $p$, is $x^2$+x-6 $\ge$ 0 and that the consequent of the conjunction of $q$ and $r$ is represented by $x$ $\le$ -3 and $x$ $\ge$ 2 respectively. I also know that we can consider $\sim$$q$ to be $x$ $\gt$ -3 (or $x$ $\not\le$ -3)

But I'm not sure how I'd go about showing that the conjunction of $p$ and $\sim$$q$ implies $r$.  Please advise.

Answer (score 1):

Assume $p\Rightarrow(q\vee r)$ and $p\wedge\neg q$ where $p:x^2+x-6\geq 0$, $q:x\leq -3$ and $r:x\geq 2$.

From $p\Rightarrow(q\vee r)$ and $p$ follows $q\vee r$.
Now argue by case analysis.
If $q$ is true then this is in contradiction with $\neg q$, hence $r$ holds.
On the other hand, from $r$ follows, clearly $r$.
Thus from $q\vee r$ we infer $r$.
But $q\vee r$ is true, hence $r$ is also true.